# Spring Data. Save BigDecimal attribute with native insert query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity:

```
@Data
public class MoneyEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
   private UUID id;

   @Column(name = "money")
   private BigDecimal money;

   @Column(name = "date")
   private Instant date;
}
```

The goal is to save it to PostgreSQL database with native query:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO performance_info (id, money, date) VALUES "
        + "(:#{#entity.id}, "
        + ":#{#entity.nav}, "
        + ":#{#entity.date} )"
        + " ON CONFLICT (date) DO NOTHING", nativeQuery = true)
void saveWithout(MoneyEntity entity);
```

The issue is that BigDecimal values convert like `bytea` instead of `numeric`. Here is the error message:

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "money" is of type numeric but expression is of type bytea Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

I have already tried to add annotation with key and class `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType")`. There is no effect.

Tried to implement custom converter:

```
@Converter
public class DecimalConverter implements AttributeConverter<BigDecimal, Double> {
    @Override
    public Double convertToDatabaseColumn(final BigDecimal attribute) {
        return attribute.doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convertToEntityAttribute(final Double dbData) {
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(dbData);
    }
}
```

The issue was that only BigDecimal can be converted to Numeric Postgres type.

Is there any way to save BigDecimal attributes with native query using Spring Data?

Comment: Your error seems to be caused by the `date` column, not the `money` column

Comment: @timsmelik sorry, I attached the wrong error message, the question is updated

Comment: Take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643592/which-postgresql-column-type-should-be-used-to-store-a-java-bigdecimal).

Comment: @dextertron_ thanks for suggestion, I still don't see the the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use **numeric** or **decimal** and specify needed precision. Take a look at Postgresql documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html).

For example:

```
t.decimal "money", precision: 12, scale: 4, default: "0.0"
```

Comment: is the example is sample of request?