# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "low_range" is of type double precision but expression is of type bytea

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "words")
public class Words implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "keyword", length = 200, unique = true)
    private String keyword;

    @Column(name = "low_range", length = 100)
    private BigDecimal lowRange;

    @Column(name = "high_range", length = 100)
    private BigDecimal highRange;
}
```

I use this query to make SQL updates:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="update processed_words set low_range = :lowRange, high_range = :highRange where keyword = :keyword", nativeQuery = true)
int updateByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword,
                    @Param("lowRange") BigDecimal lowRange,
                    @Param("highRange") BigDecimal highRange);
```

PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    high_range double precision,
    low_range double precision
)
```

When I perform the update query I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "low_range" is of type double precision but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Do you know how this issue can be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which PostgreSQL column type should be used to store a Java BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643592/which-postgresql-column-type-should-be-used-to-store-a-java-bigdecimal)

Answer (score 0):

It's always the same. Native queries and null values don't play together when using Spring Data.
Try casting the parameters that can be null with `cast(:lowRange as double precision)`

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want to use either 'decimal' or 'numeric' column type instead of 'double precision'. And you'll need to specify the precision, depending on the values being stored.

You can see the doucumentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL

Comment: I change the field to `Numeric` but still I get the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: try removing the "length" attributes on your BigDecimals?

Comment: I removed it but still I get the same error.

Comment: Can you advise please?